# Can not build Opentelemetry Cpp: undefined reference to `absl::lts_20220623::variant_internal

Tags: c++, cmake, makefile, g++, open-telemetry

I can build with their provided cmake files of https://github.com/open-telemetry/opentelemetry-cpp/, but when I trid to use `g++ -o test test.cc  -lopentelemetry_trace -lopentelemetry_exporter_otlp_grpc -lopentelemetry_resources -lopentelemetry_common` I got such error:

```
[root@OS otlp]# g++ -o test test.cc  -lopentelemetry_trace -lopentelemetry_exporter_otlp_grpc -lopentelemetry_resources -lopentelemetry_common
/usr/bin/ld: /usr/local/lib64/libopentelemetry_trace.a(tracer.cc.o): in function `opentelemetry::v1::nostd::shared_ptr<opentelemetry::v1::trace::Span>& absl::lts_20220623::variant_internal::TypedThrowBadVariantAccess<opentelemetry::v1::nostd::shared_ptr<opentelemetry::v1::trace::Span>&>()':
tracer.cc:(.text._ZN4absl12lts_2022062316variant_internal26TypedThrowBadVariantAccessIRN13opentelemetry2v15nostd10shared_ptrINS4_5trace4SpanEEEEET_v[_ZN4absl12lts_2022062316variant_internal26TypedThrowBadVariantAccessIRN13opentelemetry2v15nostd10shared_ptrINS4_5trace4SpanEEEEET_v]+0x5): undefined reference to `absl::lts_20220623::variant_internal::ThrowBadVariantAccess()'
/usr/bin/ld: /usr/local/lib64/libopentelemetry_trace.a(tracer.cc.o): in function `opentelemetry::v1::trace::SpanContext const& absl::lts_20220623::variant_internal::TypedThrowBadVariantAccess<opentelemetry::v1::trace::SpanContext const&>()':
tracer.cc:(.text._ZN4absl12lts_2022062316variant_internal26TypedThrowBadVariantAccessIRKN13opentelemetry2v15trace11SpanContextEEET_v[_ZN4absl12lts_2022062316variant_internal26TypedThrowBadVariantAccessIRKN13opentelemetry2v15trace11SpanContextEEET_v]+0x5): undefined reference to `absl::lts_20220623::variant_internal::ThrowBadVariantAccess()'
/usr/bin/ld: /usr/local/lib64/libopentelemetry_trace.a(tracer.cc.o): in function `opentelemetry::v1::context::Context const& absl::lts_20220623::variant_internal::TypedThrowBadVariantAccess<opentelemetry::v1::context::Context const&>()':
tracer.cc:(.text._ZN4absl12lts_2022062316variant_internal26TypedThrowBadVariantAccessIRKN13opentelemetry2v17context7ContextEEET_v[_ZN4absl12lts_2022062316variant_internal26TypedThrowBadVariantAccessIRKN13opentelemetry2v17context7ContextEEET_v]+0x5): undefined reference to `absl::lts_20220623::variant_internal::ThrowBadVariantAccess()'
/usr/bin/ld: /usr/local/lib64/libopentelemetry_exporter_otlp_g
```

The output seems to tell me that `absl::lts_20220623::variant_internal` is not exists in file `libopentelemetry_trace.a`,
but I have already installed `abseil` by build their project, how can I use g++ to provide abseil lib?

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

The following files are missing

```
lib file: abseil_dll.lib
dll file :abseil_dll.dll
```

I'm use vcpkg.
Install Opentelemetry-cpp

```
# vcpkg_root\installed\x64-windows\lib     
link_directories(${VCPKG_LIBRARY})    
add_executable(example "example.cc")
# abseil_dll is abseil_dll.lib
target_link_libraries(example abseil_dll opentelemetry_common opentelemetry_resources opentelemetry_trace opentelemetry_exporter_ostream_span opentelemetry_version)
#vcpkg_root\installed\x64-windows\bin. this have abseil_dll.dll
set_target_properties(example PROPERTIES RUNTIME_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY  ${VCPKG_BIN})
```